# Run python script in intellij using kotlin

Tags: python, kotlin, intellij-idea

I have an assignment to do and i need to create a server in kotlin using intellij. I need to create a function that execute a python (TheHarvester lib in github) script but with out success.
Note: I have installed the python plugin.

Here is the code:

```
fun executeScript() : String {
  val process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(
    "../resources/theHarvester/theHarvester.py"
  )
  process.waitFor()
  val reader = BufferedReader(InputStreamReader(process.inputStream))
  val message = reader.lines().collect(Collectors.joining("\n"))
  println(message)
  return ""
}
```

And here is the error message:

```
2020-02-06 21:14:21.998 [main] INFO Application - No ktor.deployment.watch patterns specified, automatic reload is not active
2020-02-06 21:14:23.885 [main] INFO Application - Responding at 0.0.0.0:8081
2020-02-06 21:14:26.089 [nettyCallPool-4-1] ERROR Application - 200 OK: GET - /execute
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "../resources/theHarvester/theHarvester.py": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1048)
```

Comment: If you would like some assistance in debugging, please post the code that is being executed as well as the entire error message. Links to images of the same are not nearly as useful because they are not searchable.

Comment: the function:

fun executeScript() : String{

    val process =Runtime.getRuntime().exec("../resources/theHarvester/theHarvester.py")
    process.waitFor()
    val reader = BufferedReader(InputStreamReader(process.inputStream))
    val message = reader.lines().collect(Collectors.joining("\n"))
    println(message)
    return ""
}

Comment: the error:

2020-02-06 21:14:21.998 [main] INFO  Application - No ktor.deployment.watch patterns specified, automatic reload is not active
2020-02-06 21:14:23.885 [main] INFO  Application - Responding at http://0.0.0.0:8081
2020-02-06 21:14:26.089 [nettyCallPool-4-1] ERROR Application - 200 OK: GET - /execute
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "../resources/theHarvester/theHarvester.py": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
 at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1048)

Comment: The error message is telling you that the file does not exist where the code is looking for it. That, or the process executing your code does not have permission to access it.

Comment: the file is exist because the autocomplete (with alt + Enter) lead me to the file.

Comment: all i need to do is very simple execute this lib ( https://github.com/laramies/theHarvester ) with kotlin.

Comment: What OS are you using?

Comment: windows 7 *****

Answer (score 0):

It is likely that the file `theHarvester.py` does not have executable permissions from the OS.

Comment: windows 7 *****

Answer (score 0):

Try using:

```
val process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(arrayOf(pythonInterpreter, absoluteScriptPath))
```

Where pythonInterpreter is absolute path to python Interpreter.